# 1980s book where humans return to Earth and find magical creatures are back

Tags: story-identification, books

I am trying to find a 1980s science fiction title about humans who return to Earth and find magical creatures are back. The cover had a tree or woods on it, and a blond male in a spacesuit who was looking at a dwarf or a gnome. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.